# Reading a variable number of lines from a file

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream

I am trying to read a variable number of lines from a file, hopefully using InputStream object. What I'm trying to do (in a very general sense) is as follows:

```
Pass in long maxLines to function
Open InputStream and OutputStream for reading/writing
WHILE (not at the end of read file AND linesWritten < maxLines)
   write to file
```

I know InputStream goes on bytes, not lines, so I'm not sure if that's a good API to use for this. If anyone has any reccomendations on what to look at in terms of a solution (other API's, different algorithm) that's be very helpful.

Comment: Google for `FileReader/FileWriter` and `BufferedReader/BufferedWriter`. It will allow you read/write the file by lines instead bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You can have something like this

```
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FILE_LOCATION"));
       while (br.readLine() != null && linesWritten < maxLines) { 
         //Your logic goes here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these:

[Buffered Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and 
[Buffered Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)

```
//Read file into String allText
InputSream fis = new FileInputStream("filein.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String line, allText = "";
try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        allText += (line + System.getProperty("line.separator")); //Track where new lines should be for output
    }
} catch(IOException e) {} //Catch any errors
br.close(); //Close reader

//Write allText to new file
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("fileout.txt"));
try {
    bw.write(allText);
} catch(IOException e) {} //Catch any errors
bw.close(); //Close writer
```

Comment: May I suggest `alltext += (line + System.getProperty("line.separator"))`? If you don't append the line separator then output file will have a large single line. Also you can optimize your code and read/write in the same loop ;-)

Comment: I will accept the first suggestion kindly, thank you. For the second, I left them separate so that the OP-er would be able to see how each work independently.

Comment: In this case optimization is not big deal anyway and I think your intention is very good, so +1 for that.